# Why is my application becoming less responsive over time?

Tags: c#, .net, performance, performancecounter

I'm debugging a C# application that becomes almost unresponsive after a few days. The application calculates memory/CPU usage every second and displays it in the footer of the main UI.

The cause for the unresponsiveness is because of the time it takes to fetch the `RawValue` of a `PerformanceCounter` ("Working Set - Private"). After a couple of days, it takes almost a second to fetch the `RawValue`, freezing the main UI thread. If I restart my computer, everything is fast again for a few days until it slowly becomes less responsive. If I recompile this application without the `PerformanceCounter` code (it's open source), it runs normally immediately.

To rule out that it's the application, here's some sample code that does the exact same thing:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    using (var memoryWorkingSetCounter = new PerformanceCounter("Process", "Working Set - Private", Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName, true))
    {
        while (!Console.KeyAvailable)
        {
            var memoryWorkingSetSw = new Stopwatch();
            memoryWorkingSetSw.Start();
            var memoryWorkingSetValue = memoryWorkingSetCounter.RawValue;
            memoryWorkingSetSw.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine(memoryWorkingSetValue.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine(memoryWorkingSetSw.Elapsed.ToString());
            Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
        }
    }
    Console.Read();
}
```

I left this running for ~2.5 days and graphed the `Elapsed` time in milliseconds:

[image: graph]

What could cause a performance counter in Windows to become slow over time? Could another app be not cleaning it up? Is there a way to debug which apps are also looking at this performance counter? I'm on Windows 10.

Comment: What happens if you decrease the scope of your `PerformanceCounter` variable to just around the `.RawValue` call? Maybe that object is holding onto data over time.

Comment: Technically this could be caused by something else than your program, like a misbehaving process that starts repeatedly and doesn't terminate.  Fragmentation of the page mapping tables is technically possible.  It is not a cheap counter, hard to muster enough patience.  Once bitten, twice shy, it is a pretty useless statistic so just drop it.  Process.WorkingSet64 is notable, it uses a very different way to obtain the info.  But to measure memory pressure imposed by your program you always favor Process.PrivateMemorySize64.

Comment: @NathanWerry well, that *could* be the problem, except that constructing this `PerformanceCounter` takes ~6+ seconds every time...

Comment: @HansPassant sure, except that it's not my program like I said. It's an open source application and they don't really accept contributions. Do you have any ideas how to debug this at a lower level on Windows? I don't see any processes starting repeatedly/don't terminate.

Comment: Check out the source code for performance counter. .Net Core it's https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter/src/System/Diagnostics/PerformanceCounter.cs, and .Net framework it's https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/services/monitoring/system/diagnosticts/PerformanceCounter.cs.

Comment: You could try copying the source to your project and measure where it's spending time

Comment: If there's not enough memory pressure to cause a GC, I'd suspect memory fragmentation over time. Might be interesting to force a GC...say every hour or so and see if your curve flattens out.

Comment: you are holding the object for long and until you stops the application scope does not comes out of `using` and it does not destroy the object; try moving this block in a method and call that method in while loop.

Comment: what happens if you dispose the counter let's say every 5 min? add another loop on top of that one

Answer (score 1):

why you declare Stopwatch inside a loop?
remove any new declaration possible inside loops.

when you do so the memory is increasing overtime and you count on garbage collector to do the work

Comment: static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // here is your declaration outside the loop
    var memoryWorkingSetSw = new Stopwatch();
    using (var memoryWorkingSetCounter = new PerformanceCounter("Process", "Working Set - Private", Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName, true))
    {
        while (!Console.KeyAvailable)
        {
           // your code
        }
    }
    Console.Read();
}